# php using mysqli convert resultset to an array and then to json

Tags: php, mysqli, resultset

I thought what I want is simple but for some reason, I'm stuck. I have the following:

```
$sql = "...";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {          
   $stmt->bind_param("sss", $x,$y,$z);
   if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $result = array(); //not sure if needed
      $stmt->bind_result($x1,$y1,$z1); //not sure if needed
      //loop resultset and put it in an array ($result);
      echo json_encode($result); // convert to json
      $stmt->close();
   }
}
```

I saw fetchAll, fetch_assoc and much more but I keep getting errors for these calls/functions as undefined. Other examples were for non prepared statements. No matter what I've tried, I failed to create an array with the resultset, what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: where and how you set $con?

Comment: [$stmt->get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)[->fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), these functions requires the [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver, available since PHP 5.3, enabled by default since PHP 5.4.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you use `bind_result`, you still need to fetch those:

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_name WHERE col4 = ? AND col5 = ? AND col6 = ?";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {          
   $stmt->bind_param('sss', $x,$y,$z);
   if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $result = array();
      $stmt->bind_result($x1,$y1,$z1);

      // You forgot this part
      while($stmt->fetch()) {
          $result[] = array('col1' => $x1, 'col2' => $y1, 'col3' => $z1);
      }

      echo json_encode($result); // convert to json
      $stmt->close();
   }
}
```

Or if you have `mysqlnd` driver on the system:

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table_name WHERE col4 = ? AND col5 = ? AND col6 = ?";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {          
   $stmt->bind_param('sss', $x,$y,$z);
   if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $data = $stmt->get_result();
      $result = array();

      while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
          $result[] = $row;
      }

      echo json_encode($result); // convert to json
      $stmt->close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess I don't have the sqlnd driver and this is why none of the "cleaner" solutions didn't work. I'm sure I have 5.4 but I will ask my hosting company.

Comment: @Amos yes you should, actually if you can, shoot out for 5.5. glad this helped